# Filtering a pandas multi-columns index dataframe while preserving column level names

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

How can I filter a multi-column index dataframe while preserving all column labels/names?

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame with a multi-column index
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]],
    columns=[["A", "A", "A", "B"], ["X", "X", "Y", "X"], [10, 20, 30, 40]],
    index=["row1", "row2"],
)
df.columns = df.columns.set_names(["level_1", "level_2", "level_3"])

print(df)

level_1  A        B
level_2  X     Y  X
level_3 10 20 30 40
row1     1  2  3  4
row2     5  6  7  8
```

When filtering for `["A", "X"]`, pandas doens't return all level names (only `level_3`). But I would like to get a dataframe with all columns level labels/names, no matter if the dataframe only consists of one single column or multiple columns.

```
print(df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice["A", "X"]])
# level_3  10  20
# row1      1   2
# row2      5   6

# That's what I am looking for:    
level_1  A   
level_2  X   
level_3 10 20
row1     1  2
row2     5  6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the inner level of columns with *square brackets* `[]` to return a [*DataFrame*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html) :

```
print(df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice["B", ["X"]]])

level_1  B
level_2  X
row1     3
row2     6
```

Comment: This is solving my issue. Having said that, I feel `Pandas` is so unintuitive at times, especially with respect to multi-column indexes :-(

Comment: To make an analogy, it's like when we select a single column from a DataFrame like this one : `df= pd.DataFrame({"col": [1, 2, 3]})`. While `df["col"]` will return a Series, `df[["col"]]` returns a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
df[[('B','X')]]
```

The first `[` is for looking up inside the columns of the dataframe, the second `[` for is for looking up >= 1 columns to get a dataframe returned and not a series, the tuple `('B','X')` specifies that we are looking up inside a multi-indexed column objects.

Comment: This is working for the problem that I originally posted. However, when adding another level to the dateframe, this solution is not working anymore (see my edited example).

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select_columns):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd

level_1  A   
level_2  X   
level_3 10 20
row1     1  2
row2     5  6
```